# Cannot connect to Redis from another server when I set up SSL certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, redis

I have two AWS EC2 instances, both running on Ubuntu 18.04, one is SSL secured (**Server 1**) and the other is not(**Server 2**). The Redis is set up on **Server 2**. Up until now, I've successfully made connections from **Server 1**, to Redis on **Server 2**. When I tried to set up an SSL certificate on **Server 2**, the connection to Redis from **Server 1** to **Server 2** failed. Both servers have *Security Groups* set to allow all inbound and outbound traffic. I figured out that once I setup SSL certificate on **Server 2**, and use the "*sudo ufw enable*" to raise firewall, the connection is broken. What would be the workaround to still have SSL certificate on both servers and still having the Redis connection?

Comment: In what way is the SSL cert related to redis?

Comment: Its not really, I think its the issue of turning firewall on when setting up the SSL certificate